# Error invalid task Ditto trying to add Swift bridging header?

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header

Ok Im just trying to add a Swift bridging header, and following tutorials added a Header file, entered nothing but my `#import` and went over to Build Settings in my plist to change the header path.

I dragged the file into here so it would have the path:

[image]

And in addition to not working, the bridging header results in error

> invalid task ('Ditto with mutable output but no other virtual output
>   node (in target 'CatsCubed MessagesExtension')

What is happening?